# Heroku - Rails 3 to 3.1 migration issues with PostgreSQL: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-postgresql

I have been following documents on how to move from Rails 3 to 3.1 and make it work on Heroku.  I used the manual upgrade technique given here: http://webtempest.com/upgrade-rails-3-to-3-1/

I have made some progress slowly but it has been mostly painful to get it to work with Heroku. My application works fine locally with rails 3.1 at the moment. I should probably let you know that in development mode, I am using mysql (simply because of having the option to use sequel pro and I haven't quite figured out how to use postgres locally yet). Thing is, I have had no issues pushing my app to heroku while in rails 3.0 and using it there with postgres and locally with mysql ever. It has always worked fine. However, now that I have moved to 3.1, using heroku cedar stack, I am running in to the following issue while following heroku docs: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Following is the error I keep bumping in to when trying to migrate or reset my application's db after pushing the code to heroku, and also when i restart the application.

```
Running rake db:reset attached to terminal... up, run.9
Couldn't drop hvifyyqdjs : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  must be owner of database hvifyyqdjs
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "hvifyyqdjs">
hvifyyqdjs already exists
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Any ideas as to how to overcome this issue? I am using the devise plugin for the 'users' mentioned here. My research on the issue led me to earlier believe that my migration might have not created the users table properly, however my very first migration file does create the user table

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

when trying to restart the app on heroku, this what i see in the logs

```
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:33603
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:962:in `async_exec': PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:962:in `exec_no_cache'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:551:in `block in exec_query'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:550:in `exec_query'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1061:in `column_definitions'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:740:in `columns'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `yield'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `default'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `columns'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:722:in `column_names'
2011-09-28T09:55:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base
```

Any help, suggestions or hints will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by myself.

One of my initializer files was doing a `find_or_create_by_id` which worked fine while development, but since I was now deploying on a fresh new application, the absence of tables was the source of that error, and was also blocking the migrate command from running and creating the missing tables.

It had nothing to do with syntax of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first error message: "ERROR:  must be owner of database hvifyyqdjs"

You (or your program) are not allowed to drop it.

Comment: hvifyyqdjs error line is just there because I used the reset command. it doesnt show up when I try to reset the app or anything else. in all other cases i get stuck with the "user" reference error mentioned above. check the new logs from heroku I just added to see what happens when I restart the app. It seems like something is up with the postgresql_adapter.rb

Comment: But the net result is that your app is not able to drop the DB, and is not able to recreate it, and that the objects it expects there are not found, or have different structures.

Comment: i see. my guess is, `hvifyyqdjs` seems to be a database related to Heroku, so I can't quite get access to it. As Erwin pointed out, the issue is the `WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass` line using '"users"'. The double quotes in quotes. Why it is using that and how to change that is something i don't know and could use help with.

Comment: BTW: in the case of database errors, it is often better to check the database logfile. Frameworks tend to bend errors wrong and cause a lot of cascading errors. That was also the nature of my "look at the first error, ignore the rest" reflex.